# Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I keep getting this error when I run this code, and I can't figure out why. I think it may be an issue with my data?

```
d=data.frame(date=as.Date(c("1971-09-01", "1991-12-01", "1994-12-01",       
"2000-01-01", "2002-08-01", "2005-08-01")), 
event=c("birth", "entered college", "BS", "entered grad school", "MS",    
"PhD"))

ggplot() +
scale_x_date(limits=as.Date(c("1970-1-1", "2010-12-31"))) +
scale_y_continuous(name="", breaks=NA, limits=c(0,1)) +
geom_vline(data=d, mapping=aes(xintercept=date), color="blue") +
geom_text(data=d, mapping=aes(x=date, y=0, label=event), size=4,     
angle=90, vjust=-0.4, hjust=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `geom_vline` doesn't like Date values for the `xintercept=` parameter. It seems to work if you convert to numeric explicitly. Try

```
ggplot() +
scale_x_date(limits=as.Date(c("1970-1-1", "2010-12-31"))) +
scale_y_continuous(name="", breaks=NULL, limits=c(0,1)) +
geom_vline(data=d, mapping=aes(xintercept=as.numeric(date)), color="blue") +
geom_text(data=d, mapping=aes(x=date, y=0, label=event), size=4,     
angle=90, vjust=-0.4, hjust=0)
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to add points to this plot? Like if I had another column that was a factor...for example: ("5th birthday", "10th birthday", "15 birthday") etc. Could I add those factors as points over this existing plot?